# For Sharepoint , In Configure Layout formatting ,the header does not take any other column field except title

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, list-form, json-formatting

This works and shows `Title` as an output:

```
{
    "elmType": "div",
    "txtContent": "[$Title]"
}
```

Below doesn't work to show the `Description` column, type for this column is "Multiline Text":

```
{
    "elmType": "div",
    "txtContent": "[$Description]"
}
```

Comment: Is this a plain text or rich text multiline text column?

Comment: multiline text column

Comment: multiline **plain** text or **rich text** column? rich text columns are not supported in JSON formatting.

Comment: Its Plain text, Rich text with picture, tables and hyperlinks is disabled or selected No

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON code looks fine. Make sure you are doing below things correctly:

1. Make sure you are showing Description field on list form like:

   [image]
2. Make sure you are using correct **internal name** of description column as JSON formatting works with internal names.

   Check this URL to find out the internal name of SharePoint column: [Find the internal name of SharePoint column](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/).

---

I have tried the same code at my end & it is working fine, check this output:

[image]

**Note**: Description text in header is updated after you change the description field value & click outside of the textbox.

Comment: Finding the internal name resolved the issue, since I imported data from excel to generate this list it was referred as field_2. Thanks for the help. Can i ask you another question... "In the similar manner why isn't a choice column getting displayed, I checked the internal name "?

Comment: If it is a single selection choice column, it should work simply by referring to its name using `[$InternalName]`.

Comment: Changed the Choice column to single selection and it works , thanks for the help.